# UPDATE SET REPLACE() matches but does not change

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, update, replace

I've seen another post about this exact thing but it's 1-1/2 years old so I thought I'd make my own...besides, the other post did not help me.  What I am trying to do is pretty straight-forward.

To be on the safe side, I tried a simple UPDATE statement on a different table, which was successful.  So, here's my problem:

```
mysql> UPDATE bugs_fulltext SET short_desc =
REPLACE(short_desc,'I don\'t know why my previous comment means.',
'I don\'t know what my previous comment means.') WHERE bug_id=452;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I'm not using wildcards nor am I using a LIKE statement.  I am telling it which record to update.  Why isn't my text changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at the query's output

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

The expression `Rows matched` is based on `WHERE bug_id=452;`. That matched.

When you executed it, the change evidently failed because the `short_desc` column didn't change because `short_desc` does not equal `'I don\'t know why my previous comment means.'`

To verify that run this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(short_desc,'I don\'t know why my previous comment means.',
'I don\'t know what my previous comment means.') replace_result
FROM bugs_fulltext WHERE bug_id=452;
```

If you getback the old value, then the old value was not in the row to begin with.

You should just directly update it (overwrite it):

```
UPDATE bugs_fulltext
SET short_desc = 'I don\'t know what my previous comment means.'
WHERE bug_id=452;
```

Comment: Hi, @Rolando.  First, I can't do a simple update because the text within short_desc is much longer than is being shown.  I'm simply trying to replace "why" with "what".  Running your query, I get back the current contents of that field.  I ran my query on a different column and this time I got: `Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0` so I think it's user error.  The column I thought had that text apparently didn't.  Thanks for leading me down the right path and for your time.